# form_for adds a div-container with css-style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a opportunity to delete the div-container, which RoR creates ?

Input:

```
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => user_sign_in_path(@user) do |f| %>
<p>
```

Output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user/sign_in" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="MT0OhRtfupZvi28m7bFN31JdZXyiFCGisbENml4cdcg=" /></div>
    <p>
```

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
```

**I don't want that!**

It's normal that there are two `hidden-text-inputs`?

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="MT0OhRtfupZvi28m7bFN31JdZXyiFCGisbENml4cdcg=" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior of `form_for`. Here's an official explanation for this:

> HTML contains something extra: a div element with two hidden input
>   elements inside. This div is important, because the form cannot be
>   successfully submitted without it. The first input element with name
>   utf8 enforces browsers to properly respect your form's character
>   encoding and is generated for all forms whether their actions are
>   "GET" or "POST". The second input element with name authenticity_token
>   is a security feature of Rails called cross-site request forgery
>   protection, and form helpers generate it for every non-GET form
>   (provided that this security feature is enabled).

You can read more about this in the **[Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)**.

Comment: Ok. I can't delete the div-container. Can I change it ? There is no id or something I could at to my .css.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it as that particular div wraps around the hidden elements. Also, the div `<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">` is given this particular style so that other form elements doesn't shift down. This is actually good. You don't get extra spacing because of hidden elements.

Comment: OH wait. I confused the form_for-style with the .text_field-style. WRONG-Input: `<%= user_form_builder.password_field :password, :html => {:class => 'form-control input-xs', :placeholder => 'Passwort'}%>` | RIGHT-Input: `<%= user_form_builder.password_field :password, class => 'form-control input-xs', :placeholder => 'Passwort'%>` So it has nothing to do with the form_for. Sorry.

Comment: form_for has :enforce_utf8 and :authenticity_token options, setting both to false gives me an EMPTY div... no good.